# Locust master-slave on k8s, delete all pods when test complete

Tags: kubernetes, locust

I'm running Locust in master-slave mode on k8s, I need to auto delete all locust pods when a test is completed. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: You can try to make a script that runs at the end of locust test, that makes kubernetes `api` call to delete all pods in specific `namespace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service and deployment type Job for master and slave. Job kind in k8s take care of deleting the pods upon completion.